# Python. Asyncio. Асинхронные чтение и запись файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

Как с помощью asyncio реализовать чтение и запись файла ?

Comment: Возможно, это лучше подойдёт:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Асинхронно никак, но можно в executor'е.

```
import asyncio

def read_file(file_name):
    return open(file_name).read()

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, read_file, 'data.txt')
    print(data)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Если есть большое желание, то можно найти асинхронное API для обычных файлов специфичное для платформы (например, overlapped IO на Windows), хотя в подавляющем большинстве случаев синхронное API, использующее кэш, достаточно (асинхронное API или сломано или менее эффективно).